# Group cohomology of product with swapping (twisting) factors

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $M$ be a $G$-module, where $G = \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$. Define a $G$-module structure on $A = M \oplus M$ by $g \cdot (a,b) = (g \cdot b, g \cdot a)$.
What is the group cohomology $H^*(G, A)$ is terms of $H^*(G,M)$ ?

Thoughts:

I know that $H^n(G, -)$ commutes with products, but here the action on $A$ is not the diagonal action, so I'm not sure what to do here. Can we at least compute $H^1(G, A)$, provided that $H^1(G, M)=0$ ?

Comment: That does not look like a $G$-module structure to me.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : thank you. Actually, I only need $G = \Bbb Z / 2$. (It seems to work, then).

Comment: (My question comes from something like the $\Bbb C/\Bbb R$-Galois action on $\Bbb C^{\times} \times \Bbb C^{\times}$.)

Answer (score 2):

For even $n>0$, $H^n$ is the kernel of $1-g$ factored by the image of $1+g$.
The kernel of $1-g$ is the set of solutions of $(a,b)=(g\cdot b,g\cdot a)$
which is equivalent to $b=g\cdot a$. Thus the typical element of the 
kernel is $(a,g\cdot a)=(a,0)+g\cdot(a,0)$ lying in the image of $1+g$.
Therefore $H^n(G,M)=0$ for even $n>0$.

A similar calculation gives  $H^n(G,M)=0$ for odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written down is the $\Bbb Z/2$-module $M \otimes \Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/2]$.

The $G$-module $M \otimes \Bbb Z[G]$ is actually independent of the choice of action on $M$, up to isomorphism: the map $m \otimes [g] \mapsto g^-1m \otimes [g]$ gives a $G$-equivariant isomorphism to $M \otimes \Bbb Z[G]$ with the trivial action on $M$. In particular we may as well assume the action is trivial.

If you choose a resolution $0\to A_1 \to A_2 \to M \to 0$ of $M$ by free abelian groups, this gives a short exact sequence $0 \to A_1[\Bbb Z/2] \to A_2[\Bbb Z/2] \to M[\Bbb Z/2] \to 0$, so there is an associated long exact sequence in cohomology.

If I can convince you that the cohomology of $\Bbb Z^\infty[\Bbb Z/2]$ is zero in degrees larger than $0$, and that $H^0(\Bbb Z/2; A[\Bbb Z/2]) \cong A$ naturally in free abelian groups $A$, then the long exact sequence tells us that $H^*(\Bbb Z/2; M[\Bbb Z/2]) = 0$ in degrees larger than 0, and gives $H^0 \cong M$.

But observe that $$H^*(\Bbb Z/2; \Bbb Z^\infty[\Bbb Z/2]) \cong H^*(\Bbb Z/2; \Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/2])^\infty$$ and this may easily be seen to be zero at the level of the definition (in degrees larger than 0). $H^0$ is just the fixed point space, which should make the statements about it clear.

Comment: I remark that this same argument shows $M[G]$ has cohomology concentrated in degree 0 for any $G$ and any $G$-module $M$.